# AWS SES configuration for specific domain in Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ses

I'm trying to know if there is a way to configure Cloudwatch to see metrics of a specific domain, so that way I can verify how many emails have been Sent, Deliver or Bounce.

I found that I can see a general Metric of my SES, but that show the data from all domains

Comment: I'm not familiar with the topic myself, but I wonder whether this would help: [Set Up a CloudWatch Event Destination for Amazon SES Event Publishing - Amazon Simple Email Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/event-publishing-add-event-destination-cloudwatch.html) and [Monitoring Using Amazon SES Event Publishing - Amazon Simple Email Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor-using-event-publishing.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see metrics for a specific sender's domain, you can do as follows:

1. Create a configuration set

   [image]
2. Edit your newly created configuration set to add a *CloudWatch Destination* using *Message Tag* as value souce and `ses:from-domain` as dimension name (you can set the *Default Value* to 0, it doesn't matter here)

   [image]
3. Use your newly created configuration set when sending emails with SES

   You can specify a configuration set either with the `X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET` header or with the option when using the AWS SDK. See [Specifying a Configuration Set When You Send Email](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-configuration-sets-in-email.html).

After a while, you should see your domain metrics appear in CloudWatch.

If you want to have metrics for the recipient's domains, you will have to tag your emails with the recipient's domain. This can be done with `X-SES-MESSAGE-TAGS` header (e.g. `X-SES-MESSAGE-TAGS: domain=gmail.com`) in your email or with the SDK (see [SendEmail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SendEmail.html)/[SendTemplatedEmail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SendTemplatedEmail.html) in the API that supports tagging). Then, in step 2 above, instead of specifying `ses:from-domain`, you specify `domain` (or whatever you choose). Note that this **can quickly create lots of custom metrics and become pricey** (see [CloudWatch pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/)).

More information in [Monitoring Using Amazon SES Event Publishing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor-using-event-publishing.html)  and [Set Up a CloudWatch Event Destination for Amazon SES Event Publishing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/event-publishing-add-event-destination-cloudwatch.html).

Comment: I think he is asking about specific "recipient" domain.

Comment: Not sure, let's wait for a feedback. Anyway it is also possible using custom tags, I'll update my answer when he replies.

Comment: @JamesDean updated my answer for recipient's domain.

Comment: Hi sorry I didn’t answer ! Yeah is for a recipient domain sorry that I didn’t specified that. I’m doing this because I want to know how many emails sent my clients that way I can know if it will be necessary to offer them an increase of emails per month, I will try this over the weekend and comeback with an answer. Thanks for the fast answer btw !!!